# How do i make all build scripts to appear before plugins

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

That is my code, and when
[image]
try to sync, I get this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
        build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Chiro\build.gradle': 12: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script
        See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block
        @ line 12, column 1.
        buildscript{
        ^
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the builscript at line 12

put it at line 1

Refer this official docs [External dependencies for the build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies)

If you are getting google repo error, try to remove google() under repositories and use mavenCentral()

Comment: I have done that, and i am getting this error now:                    Gradle sync failed: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle' (41 s 225 ms)

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Dickens AS Answer, you need to change this configuration in settings.gradle(Project Settings)

Instead of this :
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

you can use this:
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)